# Serializing PostData object for PUT request

Tags: javascript, html

I have a form script that is sending a formData object on POST requests. 
Is there a way to somehow serialize that object as a normal query string so that i can send it to server using other HTTP methods ?

Answer (score 0):

Using [jQuery serializeObject plugin](https://github.com/hongymagic/jQuery.serializeObject), or:

```
var qs = "?";

for(var p in YourObj)
{
    qs += "&" + encodeURIComponent(YourObj[p]);
}
```

however this assumes your object only has properties one layer deep. Or if some of the YourObj properties are objects:

```
var qs = "?", typ;

for(var p in YourObj)
{
    typ = typeof(YourObj[p]);
    qs += "&" + encodeURIComponent( 
        ['string','number'].indexOf(typ) >-1 ? YourObj[p] : JSON.stringify(YourObj[p]) 
    );
}
```

Comment: Bu FormData i mean : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/XMLHttpRequest/FormData